# Search with or without regular expression with a 'DT' table

Tags: r, datatables, dt

With the **DT** package, it is possible to search in a table with regular expressions:

```r
datatable(
  data = iris,
  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE)
  )
)
```

But I would like to have the possibility to search with or without a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to go is to use the **SearchBuilder** extension.

The **SearchBuilder** extension already defines numerous useful search criteria for strings, such as "contains", "starts with", "ends with", etc. And you can add a custom criterion if you want. Here I've added a criterion *"matches regex"*, which allows to search with a regular expression:

```r
library(DT)

datatable(
  iris,
  extensions = "SearchBuilder",
  options = list(
    dom = "Qlfrtip",
    searchBuilder = list(
      conditions = list(
        string = list(
          regex = list(
            conditionName = "matches regex",
            init = JS(
              "function (that, fn, preDefined = null) {",
              "  var el =  $('<input/>').on('input', function() { fn(that, this) });",
              "  if (preDefined !== null) {",
              "     $(el).val(preDefined[0]);",
              "  }",
              "  return el;",
              "}"
            ),
            inputValue = JS(
              "function (el) {",
              "  return $(el[0]).val();",
              "}"
            ),
            isInputValid = JS(
              "function (el, that) {",
              "  return $(el[0]).val().length !== 0;",
              "}"
            ),
            search = JS(
              "function (value, regex) {",
              "  var reg = new RegExp(regex, 'g');",
              "  return reg.test(value);",
              "}"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

[image]